# What are the issues associated with enabling threadsafe in Google Appengine?

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, thread-safety

This is going to be a self-answered question, but I thought that such a specific question (and answer) could be of use to others...

What are the potential issues associated with enabling multi-threading in Google App Engine (GAE/J) using the  element in appengine-web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at this for a project I'm working on, and I have written up what I have found in an analysis here: http://devcon5.blogspot.com

I would very much appreciate any comments or additional questions I should cover.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing to mention is that during the loading request of an instance no additional requests are handled in other threads. Only after the first request is completely finished will the instance go into a multi-threaded mode. This is especially noticeable on loading the initial instance after a deploy (or after all instances died without idle instances).

This will impact applications that use URLFetch to call other servlets in the same application. The first request will try to call the same instance first, but that instance won't handle the call yet. After a timeout the scheduler will spin-up a second instance, after which the request is handled. (Latency on-top-of latency...)

Comment: Excellent Ludo, both from the (lack of) benefits point of view (a future post of mine) and also from a gotcha point of view. OK if I add to my post....I can attribute you and link to you if you tell me where.